# css3 animation not always working after onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

Consider the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#item').css({
        webkitTransform: 'translate(100px, 100px)' 
    });
});
```

The element I try to translate has the following css:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-property: transform;
```

So I would expect a moving element during 1 seconds. Checkout the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5g3/)

The strange thing is that the animation sometimes happens and sometimes not (meaning it is without any animation at 100px, 100px). So the question is why does it not always work, because I'm waiting for the onLoad before I do anything ?

Comment: could be just me but your example isnt doing anything.

Comment: Not just you Tony, doesn't do anything for me either.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5g3/4/) is an updated version. I've added a timeout around the code inside the onLoad callback

Comment: I must add that in safari it works as expected and in Chrome and Firefox I get the problem described above

Answer (score 0):

try with document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function()
   $('#item').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate(100px,100px)"}); 
});
```

Comment: same result: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5g3/9/), sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){});` === `$(function(){})` http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

You set the transition to 1000ms, or 1 second.  Increase this number to 10000ms and it should animate for 10 seconds.

Comment: true, I ment 1s :) I also have the same situation with 10s that when I hit 'Run' nothing happens with the blue div on the end position

Answer (score 0):

Hi the animation can be done purely using CSS3 animation. The code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    @keyframes moving {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }

        to {
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -moz-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -ms-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -o-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            transform: translate(100px, 100px);
        }
     }

    @-moz-keyframes moving {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }

        to {
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -moz-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -ms-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -o-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            transform: translate(100px, 100px);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes moving {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }

        to {
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -moz-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -ms-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            -o-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
            transform: translate(100px, 100px);
        }
    }
    div#item {
        background-color:blue;
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
        -webkit-animation: moving 1s;
        -moz-animation: moving 1s;
        -ms-animation: moving 1s;
        -o-animation: moving 1s;
        animation: moving 1s;
    }
</style>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5g3/11/

Comment: I changed a jsfiddle setting to onLoad and now it works too ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5g3/13/)). Still weird, because I would say that this is not different than using `$(function(){..})`